# Best practice for using MediatorLiveData only by present data

Tags: android, android-livedata

What is the best practice for using the MediatorLiveData with multiple sources?

I have a MediatorLiveData in the ViewModel, that is accessed from the view for the data, that should finally be presented.

The MediatorLiveData depends on multiple other LiveDatas. Some of them come from the repository layer, some of them have to be processed in the ViewModel before they can be accessed from the MediatorLiveData and some of them come from the View.

So my current implementation looks like the following schema:

```
public MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
   LiveData<Foo> liveData1;
   LiveData<Bar> liveData2;
   LiveData<FooBar> liveData3;
   //Some other LiveDatas

   MediatorLiveData liveDataForView

   public MyViewModel() {
      liveDataForView = new MediatorLiveData();
      //Do some preprocessing with some of the LiveData
      setupForView();
   }

   public MediatorLiveData getLiveDataForView() {
      return liveDataForView;
   }

   private void setupForView() {
      liveDataForView.addSource(liveData1, (foo -> {
         if(liveData1.getValue() != null && liveData2.getValue() != null && liveData3.getValue() != null /*&& some other LiveData-checks*/)
            liveDataForView.setValue(/*Some combinations of the LiveDatas*/);
      }));
      //Add sources to the MediatorLiveData for any other LiveData
   }
}
```

With this implementation I assert, that the value of the output LiveData is set after every LiveData is present.
In some cases, if I left some null-checks out, I got a NullPointerException.
But this solution seems a bit messy to me, because for each LiveData I have to add to the ViewModel, I have to add it to every single one of the sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need some tuples:

```
public class Tuple2<S, T> {
    public final S first;
    public final T second;

    public Tuple2(S first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Tuple3<S, T, U> {
    public final S first;
    public final T second;
    public final U third;

    public Tuple3(S first, T second, U third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Tuple4<S, T, U, V> {
    public final S first;
    public final T second;
    public final U third;
    public final V fourth;

    public Tuple4(S first, T second, U third, V fourth) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
        this.fourth = fourth;
    }
}
```

Once you have your tuples, you can write helper functions that work akin to `Transformations.map` except now you could do:

```
public class LiveDataTransformations {
    private LiveDataTransformations() {}

    public static <S, T> LiveData<Tuple2<S,T>> ifNotNull(LiveData<S> first, LiveData<T> second) {
        MediatorLiveData<Tuple2<S, T>> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mediator.addSource(first, (_first) -> {
            T _second = second.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple2(_first, _second));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(second, (_second) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple2(_first, _second));
            }
        });

        return mediator;
    }

    public static <S, T, U> LiveData<Tuple3<S,T,U>> ifNotNull(LiveData<S> first, LiveData<T> second, LiveData<U> third) {
        MediatorLiveData<Tuple3<S, T, U>> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mediator.addSource(first, (_first) -> {
            T _second = second.getValue();
            U _third = third.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple3(_first, _second, _third));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(second, (_second) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            U _third = third.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple3(_first, _second, _third));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(third, (_third) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            T _second = second.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple3(_first, _second, _third));
            }
        });

        return mediator;
    }

    public static <S, T, U, V> LiveData<Tuple4<S,T,U, V>> ifNotNull(LiveData<S> first, LiveData<T> second, LiveData<U> third, LiveData<V> fourth) {
        MediatorLiveData<Tuple4<S, T, U, V>> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mediator.addSource(first, (_first) -> {
            T _second = second.getValue();
            U _third = third.getValue();
            V _fourth = fourth.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null && _fourth != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple4(_first, _second, _third, _fourth));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(second, (_second) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            U _third = third.getValue();
            V _fourth = fourth.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null && _fourth != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple4(_first, _second, _third, _fourth));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(third, (_third) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            T _second = second.getValue();
            V _fourth = fourth.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null && _fourth != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple4(_first, _second, _third, _fourth));
            }
        });

        mediator.addSource(fourth, (_fourth) -> {
            S _first = first.getValue();
            T _second = second.getValue();
            U _third = third.getValue();
            if(_first != null && _second != null && _third != null && _fourth != null) {
                mediator.setValue(new Tuple4(_first, _second, _third, _fourth));
            }
        });

        return mediator;
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
LiveData<???> liveDataForView;

private void setupForView() {
   LiveData<Tuple3<Foo, Bar, FooBar>> intermediate =  LiveDataTransformations.ifNotNull(liveData1, liveData2, liveData3);
   liveDataForView = Transformations.map(intermediate, (tuple) -> {
       Foo foo = tuple.first;
       Bar bar = tuple.second;
       FooBar fooBar = tuple.third;

       return /*Some combinations of the LiveDatas*/
   });
}
```

**EDIT:** You can use the library https://github.com/Zhuinden/livedata-combinetuple-kt to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I understand you right: 
If I have to add some further LiveDatas while implementation, I have to add a new Tuple-Class, where I add the xth LiveData to the mediator and then adapt the setupForView for processing the xth element?

Comment: Yeah, but it is the [same strategy that RxJava uses](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/621b8cda977605f91b8620a6e4e34f6c1cc89455/src/main/java/io/reactivex/Observable.java#L4420-L4427).

Comment: It might be possible to make a smarter method that can handle it for any N array, as long as the `vararg` LiveData could be mapped into a tuple of the same arity. That way you don't have to type so much. The method `zipArray` gave me the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add it to every expression of every single source, as you are not accessing the variable foo in your lambda expression.
Therefore you can call a helper function instead from all your lambda expressions (or maybe you are even able to reuse the same lambda expression for all sources, can't test that atm.), that way you only need to define the checks inside your single helper function.