# MediatorLiveData binding directly from ViewModel to View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I'm trying to enable/disable a button when 4 EditTexts have more than X chars and email is valid (ignore the xml, still applying styles):

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_login_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:enabled="@{viewModel.createAccountDetailsValid}"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="create account "
            android:onClick="@{(theView) -> handler.onCreateClick(theView, viewModel)}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_login_companyText"
    />
```

I got it working using **MediatorLiveData with the 4 MutableLiveData** that the button depends on, but I find that I'm going **against the MVVM standards** by doing this, but was the only way it works since MediatorLiveData only allows addSource if has at least 1 observer, have a look at the code:

on my View Model:

```
//USER DATA
val email: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val name: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val surname: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val company: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val createAccountDetailsValid: MediatorLiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData()

fun populateMediator(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        createAccountDetailsValid.observe(owner, Observer {  })
        createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(email) {
            createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
        }
        createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(name) {
            createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
        }
        createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(surname) {
            createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
        }
        createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(company) {
            createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
        }
    }

private fun isCreateAccountDetailsValid() : Boolean {
    if(email.value == null || name.value == null || surname.value == null || company.value == null) return false
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email?.value!!).matches() && name.value?.length!! >= 3 && surname.value?.length!! >= 3 && company.value?.length!! >= 3
}
```

on my fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_login, container,false)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.handler = LoginHandler()
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
    viewModel.setLifecycleOwner(this as LifecycleOwner)
    return binding.root
}
```

Like I said it's working but ViewModel has a reference to View (LifecycleOwner), yes I could put the empty observer on the Fragment and don't need to pass the LifecycleOwner to the ViewModel but still doesn't feel right, maybe I'm being a bit perfectionist here but I bet there's another way of binding directly from the ViewModel instead of having to have to set isEnable observing the MediatorLiveData in the Fragment?

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need `createAccountDetailsValid.observe(owner, Observer {  })`

Comment: @Blackbelt yes I need to because of this 

`@MainThread
    public <S> void addSource(@NonNull LiveData<S> source, @NonNull f (existing != null) {
            return;
        }
        if (hasActiveObservers()) {
            e.plug();
        }
    }`

Basically, it doesn't have any observers doesn't plug as you can see, so I need to have one for some weird reason.

Comment: you don't need that. `databinding` is gonna observe that for you. Mediator is a `LiveData` object. Do you need to `Observe` for every `LiveData` object you have?

Comment: that's what I thought as well but if I remove that observe the binding stops working, maybe I'm doing something else wrong here.

Comment: that's probably the case. Are you `setting/posting` anything on `name/surname/company/email` ?

Comment: I think I found the issue here, was when I was doing addSource at that time the view hasn't been created which means the I was doing it too early maybe? and the databinding didn't observe at that time

Comment: that doesn't make any sense

Comment: What would be the best time to call addSource to the MediatorLiveData? init of the view model?

Comment: it doesn't matter. E.g I use `lazy`

Comment: Yeah, it's working, might have done something wrong and ended up fixing by complicating, it just worked the way I have thought it would from the beginning, thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Consider doing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271762/best-practice-for-using-mediatorlivedata-only-by-present-data/54292960#54292960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has Blackbelt comment I should have been doing something wrong and ended up complicating and fix the issue while trying to make it work.

Has he said databinding observes and you can addSource on the viewModel init like I did and got it working:

```
 val createAccountResult: MutableLiveData<Resource<Void>> = MutableLiveData()
val loginResult: MutableLiveData<Resource<Void>> = MutableLiveData()

//USER DATA
val email: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val name: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val surname: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
val company: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

var createAccountDetailsValid: MediatorLiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData()

init {
    createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(email) {
        createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
    }
    createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(name) {
        createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
    }
    createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(surname) {
        createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
    }
    createAccountDetailsValid.addSource(company) {
        createAccountDetailsValid.value = isCreateAccountDetailsValid()
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help @Blackbelt