# Calculation Problem in Helper Class - Return is hit before calculation

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

My current problem is that I wanna create a Helper class that calculates my costs (stored in database) so that everything is organized better (because I need this calculation in two of my Activities).

Right now the calculation code (which is working fine) is just written inside the two Activities (which makes everything rather ugly).

So: I created a "CostIntervalHelper"-Class.

I put my code there and changed a few things but I am hitting a big problem right now. To explain it better, first here you go with the code of the calculation method:

```
 public BigDecimal calculateMonthlyCosts(SubViewModel subViewModel, Context context){
    //set this two times just for debugging reasons to see if the calculation actually works
    cMonthly = new BigDecimal(0);

    subViewModel.getAllMonthlyCosts().observe((LifecycleOwner) context, new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
            cMonthly = new BigDecimal(0);
            if (bigDecimal != null) {
                cMonthly = cMonthly.add(bigDecimal);
            }
        }
    });

    subViewModel.getAllBiannuallyCosts().observe((LifecycleOwner) context, new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
            cBiannually = new BigDecimal(0);
            if (bigDecimal != null) {
                cBiannually = cBiannually.add(bigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal(6), 2));
            }
        }
    });

    subViewModel.getAllYearlyCosts().observe((LifecycleOwner) context, new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
            cYearly = new BigDecimal(0);
            if (bigDecimal != null) {
                cYearly = cYearly.add(bigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal(12), 2));
                cMonthly = cMonthly.add(cBiannually).add(cYearly);
            }
        }
    });

    //return is hit before the calculation so it only returns "0"
    return cMonthly;
}
```

Now here we go with the problem (already put some comments in the code):

Whenever I call for the method, the return cMonthly is called first.
In Debug-Mode I checked and I can say: AFTER the return statement was hit, the calculation gets done (in the right way).

Now I need an idea or example how I can make my code FIRST (in the right order) do all the `subViewModel.getAll(Monthly/Biannually/Yearly)Costs().[...]` methods and AFTERWARDS hit the return statement.

I know this is a bit tricky because I am using LiveData/ViewModel but maybe someone has an idea! Would be awesome! Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public BigDecimal calculateMonthlyCosts(SubViewModel subViewModel...) {
> ```

If you are using LiveData, then your calculations should not immediate in the form of synchronous function.

You don't want to return a BigDecimal, you want to create a LiveData that is based on chain between your other LiveData that will update the BigDecimal when either of the LiveData changes.

For this, you should create a single MediatorLiveData, and should observe that LiveData to receive the latest value of the BigDecimal whenever any of its "components" change.

```
public LiveData<BigDecimal> calculateMonthlyCosts(SubViewModel subViewModel) {
    MediatorLiveData<BigDecimal> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>() {
        private BigDecimal cMonthly = new BigDecimal(0);
        private BigDecimal cBiannually = new BigDecimal(0);
        private BigDecimal cYearly = new BigDecimal(0);

        {
            addSource(subViewModel.getAllMonthlyCosts(), new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
                    if (bigDecimal != null) {
                        cMonthly = cMonthly.add(bigDecimal);
                        setValue(cMonthly);
                    }
                }
            });

            addSource(subViewModel.getAllBiannuallyCosts(), new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
                    if (bigDecimal != null) {
                        cBiannually = cBiannually.add(bigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal(6), 2));
                        setValue(cMonthly); // TODO: ???
                    }
                }
            });

            addSource(subViewModel.getAllYearlyCosts(), new Observer<BigDecimal>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
                    if (bigDecimal != null) {
                        cYearly = cYearly.add(bigDecimal.divide(new BigDecimal(12), 2));
                        cMonthly = cMonthly.add(cBiannually).add(cYearly);
                        setValue(cMonthly);
                    }
                }
            });
         }
    };

    return mediator;
}
```

Please note that I am not 100% certain about your business logic and might need to follow the way of "using tuples to combine multiple LiveData" as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044738/2413303) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292960/2413303).

You can also refer to [this video](https://youtu.be/2rO4r-JOQtA?t=645).