# How to change a LiveData value based on two others LiveData values from a ViewModel

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

I want to change a LiveData value based on two others LiveData values but I don't know how to do it.

I know that I can use LiveData.map() but that only works if I want to change a LiveData value based on another LiveData value.

I have a Repository class with this two LiveData variables:

```
val isLoadingDataFromDatabase = listForecasts.map { it.isEmpty() }
val isLoadingDataFromNetwork = MutableLiveData<Boolean>().apply { value = true }
```

Then, I have a ViewModel with this LiveData variable:

```
val showLoadingIndicator = repository.isLoadingDataFromDatabase
```

I could also use:

```
val showLoadingIndicator = repository.isLoadingDataFromDatabase.map { it == true }
```

However, what I would like to do it to change showLoadingIndicator value to true only when isLoadingDataFromDatabase and isLoadingDataFromNetwork are both true.

I can't use the observe() method because it is used inside the ViewModel and it doesn't have a lifecycle

Comment: MediatorLiveData is a solution to combine multiple source 
read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52306675/7972699. This should help you