# Android Room: Trigger Query when Another Table Modified

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have my DAO set up as follows:

```
public interface AllocationDao {
    @Query("SELECT * from allocation")
    LiveData<List<Allocation>> getAllocations();

    @Query("SELECT * from allocation where id = :id")
    Allocation getAllocationForId(int id);

    @Query("SELECT * from lineitem where allocation_id = :id")
    List<LineItem> getLineItemsForId(int id);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Allocation... allocations);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(LineItem... lineItems);
}
```

Is it possible to trigger the observer for `getAllocations()` when I do an `insertAll(LineItem... lineItems)`? What is happening now is when I do an insert to LineItem, I need the Allocation query to run, but since the query is unmodified, it's not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MediatorLiveData`

Firstly, add a method to your dao which observes `lineItems`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM lineItem")
LiveData<List<Allocation>>  observeLineItems();
```

Secondly use MediatorLiveData to observe both the `LineItems` and `Allocations`

```
val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<R>()
mediatorLiveData.addSource(observeLineItems()){
   // extract this to a single function that will be called each time either source changes
}
mediatorLiveData.addSource(getAllocations()){
   // extract this to a single function that will be called each time either source changes
}
```

Note: I've not tested this out so it may not be syntactically perfect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079290/764624) has a nice extension function which makes the above cleaner